# Read from file generically

Tags: java, file, generics, serialization

I am trying to fast read from file. I used JSON format before but then I decreased file size using binary file. I just cannot figure out how to use generic reading from file.

For JSON I used TypeReference

```
public <T> T read(final TypeReference<T> type, String path, String fileName) {
    T data = null;

    try {
        checkDir(path);
        String pathAll = homePath + path + "/" + fileName;

        data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File(pathAll), type);

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

but for binary file I cannot find anything similar. So I just used suppresswarning

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T readSerializable(String path, String fileName) {
    Object data = null;
    checkDir(path);
    String pathAll = homePath + path + "/" + fileName;

    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathAll));
        data = inputStream.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return (T) data;
}
```

Is there any way how to use typereference for reading from binary file as well? Or should I just leave it with warning, but isn't it slower then using JSON because Java needs to "figure out" what the proper type should it be? The size of files is about half size then with json but if it should get significantly slower for big data I will stick to json anyway...

So I have generally two questions: 
1) can I use typereference for second example?
2) if not/yes will that be faster/slower then first (other) type of reading?

Thanks

Comment: thanks, I know about this one, that's why I am trying to get there the TypeReference of T and not just T.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass warning by providing `Class<T>` object like this:

```
public <T extends Serializable> T readSerializable(String path, Class<T> clazz) {
    ObjectInputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        return clazz.cast(is.readObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I don't think that `ObjectOutputStream` what type it reads. In the end it returns `Object`. The target cast is provided by developer. So I guess there are is no performance decrease.

Comment: thanks. What is better option there, to just call the method with User.class or create TypeReference there as well? Is there any difference between these two actually?

Comment: I think you will be good with `User.class` because you just read the object as stream of bytes and then cast it to what you want. It works with generics too. For example: you can serialize `C<Integer>` and after deserialization you will get `C<Serializable>` (or `C<Object>` if you remove constraint), but you can cast it to `C<Integer>`. In JSON case it is different because unmarshaller creates instance of object and then set its properties. However, due to type erasure the inner type is not available in runtime, so you have to provide it using `TypeReference`